# How can I add min and max Threshold line in Google Line Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I have added line chart on my web-app and I need to add or highlight a constant line showing up in red for min-threshold value for this parameter and max-threshold for this parameter. I have gone the [Google Line Charts Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) but couldn't find any such options available in it. I wonder how anyone other also haven't ask this question on community so far. While searching a lot for solution to this problem I found one Fiddle related to this but it is adding an another line parameter and it showing tool-tip as that value, which I don't want to show on line chart. Also, adding it as another line in chart I find inefficient.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Fiddle I have referred in question is https://jsfiddle.net/8p6z4631/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there aren't any standard options for adding *threshold* lines or markers

adding another series is the only way

you can use the following option to disable tooltips...

```
enableInteractivity: false
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', ''],
    ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      250],
    ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      250],
    ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      250],
    ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      250],
    ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      250]
  ]);

  var options = {
    seriesType: "line",
    series: {
      5: {
        type: "steppedArea",
        color: '#FF0000',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        areaOpacity: 0,
        enableInteractivity: false
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note**: recommend loading the newer library `loader.js` instead of `jsapi`, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...

Answer (score 1):

You can override the automatically generated ticks with set values.

For example:

```
vAxes: {
  0: {
    title:'Left Axis Title',
    ticks: [
      0,
      {v:460, f:'Minimum Recommended'},
      {v:1840, f:'Maximum Safe'},
      {v:2300, f:'100%'}
    ]
     }
  }
```